# Azure: Cannot use output from Linked Template in IF condition

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a Virtual network using ARM template with multiple subnets. I have a linked template which creates NSGs,route table and assigns it to a specific subnet. I'm using copy to create multiple subnets. Route table should be assigned to only one particular subnet. I control this using If condition. The issue here is i'm not able to use the linked template output in the If condition. It fails with below error.

> '{
>     "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidTemplate",
>       "message": "Unable to process template language expressions for resource
>   '/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/' at line '143' and column '9'. 'The provided
>   arguments for template language function 'if' is not valid: all arguments should be of type 'boolean'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions#if for usage details.'"
>     }
>   }'

Main Template (Subnet Creation snippet):-

```
"copy": [
      {
        "name": "subnets",
        "count": "[length(parameters('subnetList'))]",
        "input": {
          "name": "[parameters('subnetList')[copyIndex('subnets')].name]",
          "properties": {
            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetList')[copyIndex('subnets')].addressprefix]",
            "networkSecurityGroup": "[if(equals(parameters('subnetList')[copyIndex('subnets')].name, 'GatewaySubnet'), json('null'), variables('nsgId'))]",
            "routeTable": "[if(bool(parameters('subnetList')[copyIndex('subnets')].useRouteTable), reference('routeTableDeployment').outputs.resourceID.value, json('null'))]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Route Table (Output snippet):-

```
 "outputs": {
    "resourceID": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', variables('routeTableName')]"
        }
    }
}
```

It works if I define a variable and pass it to if condition similar to nsg as below:-

```
"routeTableId": {
  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', 'routeTableName')]"
}

"routeTable": "[if(bool(parameters('subnetList')[copyIndex('subnets')].useRouteTable), variables('routeTableId'), json('null'))]"
```

Comment: You can try to change outputs like this: `"outputs": {
    "resourceID": {
        "type": "object",
        "value":  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', variables('routeTableName')]"
    }
}`

Comment: Charles - above output returns string. I would like to return an object from outputs and use it in If conditions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-logical#if, here it says IF accepts object type for trueValue and falseValue. Also the error returned is unclear. It says "The provided arguments for template language function 'if' is not valid: all arguments should be of type 'boolean'. " From the doc IF does not need all arguments to be type bool

Comment: The IF has three arguments, condition must be bool value and others not. I see that you said you just changed "routeTableId" into a variable and the template worked. So I'm glad that you can give more details about where is your problem.

Comment: This seems to be product issue. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9950 is the link